# Providing relative file path

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I have text files in my resource file and I'd like to be able to provide a path for this file to `std::ifstream`.  Neither `:\file_name.txt` nor `..\file_name.txt` works.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative path for fstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068921/relative-path-for-fstream)

Comment: @Als: I don't think so. Qt resources are not filesystem objects, they're bundled inside the executable at link time.

Comment: That question has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @user336635: you are referring to Qt resources, compiled with `qrc`, right?

Comment: @Als but there wasn't satisfying answer given to yes, similar question. It would be nice if the question could actually get correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Qt resource files are not filesystem files. Those files are loaded in memory as static char arrays. You can see for yourself looking in your build directory for qrc_*.cpp files. You can get data from there if you want, or you might want to use [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextstream.html#QTextStream-2) for reading those, using the [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html) constructor with a [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html).

You don't specify what you want to do exactly, but this is a sample that reads what is inside the file:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file(":/test.txt");
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
       qFatal("Failed to open file.");
       return -1;
    }
    QString text = stream.readAll();
    if (text.isNull()) {
       qDebug("Failed to read file.");
       return -1;
    }
    qDebug("File content is: %s. Bye bye.", qPrintable(text));
    return 0;
}
```