# How to read and write a file

Tags: c++, stdvector, readfile

I have a file named read.txt `E:\My_project\dictionary database\read.txt` and it looks like

```
1245
15
12
454564
122
....
```

I want to read the read.txt line by line and want to save these value into a vector and finally output the vector and write the values of vector into another txt file named write.txt which will be look same as read.txt?? How can i do this in C++???

I tried to read the value from file like this:

```
  ifstream ifs("read.txt", ifstream::in);
```

But i dont understand where to keep the read.txt file.What should be the location of read.txt and write.txt???

Edited:
if i use vector to save the input from the text i m getting an error:

```
int textLine;
  vector<int> input;

  ifstream ifs("C:\\Users\\Imon-Bayazid\\Desktop\\k\\read.txt", ifstream::in);

  if (ifs.good())   {

        while (!ifs.eof()) {
              getline(ifs, textLine);
              input.push_back(textLine);
        }

        ifs.close();

  } else
      cout << "ERROR: can't open file." << endl;


        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
          cout<<input.at(i);
```

Comment: Why did you add the **vector** tag to this post? Should you maybe do something with a std::vector object?

Comment: Try the absolute path for the `open` bit?

Comment: .. Glad to help you guys with the heads up as to the problem. You all get one each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name of the file is hardcoded to `"read.txt"`, the file must be in the same folder as your executable. If the location of the file is not going to change, you can hardcode full path:

```
ifstream ifs("E:\\My_project\\dictionary database\\read.txt", ifstream::in);
```

(note the doubled backslashes: that's for the C++ compiler to treat them as regular slashes).

Comment: I have edited my question could you please see this to answer ?? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @user2029069 You get an error because you cannot use `getline(ifs, textLine);` to read an `int`. You need to use `ifs >> textLine` for that. I suggest renaming `textLine` to something more appropriate, e.g. `intValue`.

Comment: @user2029069 the same thing applies: use `<<` to output `int`s into a file, and don't forget to add `endl`. Something like `ofs << myInt << endl;` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your binary is located in `E:\My_project`, then you need to adjust the path of the file you are opening to:
`ifstream ifs("./dictionary database/read.txt", ifstream::in);`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068921/relative-path-for-fstream) related question.

Comment: I have edited my question could you please see this to answer ??

Answer (score 1):

You can give the absolute path of the file when you open it:

```
ifstream ifs("E:\\My_project\\dictionary database\\read.txt", ifstream::in);
```

Or you you can move the executable program which reads the file in the same directory where the file is.

Edit:

By declaring your vector like this: `vector<int> input;` you create a vector in which you can store integer values only, but what you are reading from file(`textLine`) is a string. If you only want to interpret the numbers from file as integer values you will have to use

```
input.push_back(atoi(textLine.c_str()));
```

Comment: I have edited my question could you please see this to answer ??