# fstream doesn't resolve path

Tags: c++, fstream

i am new to c++ and trying to write a simple function, that saves a string to a file.
The function works, when i pass the full path to fstream, but it doesn't resolve relative paths.

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writeToFile ()
{
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open ("/home/blabla/Documents/test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fs << " test content";

    fs.close();
}
```

This works fine, but i would like to create the file in the folder, where my program is executed, so i tried this

```
fs.open ("./test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

I also tried

```
fs.open ("~/Documents/test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

Neither of them created a new file and i did not get any error message.

I found this post, which suggests, that i can pass relative paths to fstream but only gives windows examples. 
[How to use fstream objects with relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068921/relative-path-for-fstream)

I work on Linux Mint, the target environment is debian.

I am thankful for any hints or suggestions,
Michael

Comment: What do you mean by "in the folder, where my program is executed".  Do you mean where the executable is located?

Comment: This `~/Documents/test.txt` is evalueated by the shell, while `./test.txt` should work, if you're running your program in the same directory. _"and i did not get any error message"_ You'll never get one, you have to test it after open: `if(!fs) { std::cerr << "Could not open file" << std::endl; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writeToFile () {
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open ("./test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fs << " test content";

    fs.close();
}

int main() {
    writeToFile();
}
```

works perfectly fine for me on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e54cdd9b06324050).

As you can see from the `ls` output, the file was created

```
a.out      << The executable program
main.cpp   << The source
test.txt   << The created text file
```

and `cat` at least dumps the content of the file

```
 test content
```

As mentioned in my comment, a path like `~/Documents/test.txt` is evaluated by the shell, while `./test.txt` should work for openting an existing file, if you're running your program in the same directory where the file exists.

> *"Neither of them created a new file and i did not get any error message."*

You'll never get any kind of *error message*, if [`std::fstream::open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) failed for some reason.
You have to check for the stream state after that call, like e.g.

```
 if(!fs) { std::cerr << "Could not open file" << std::endl; }
```

You may e.g. not have rights to create a file in this directory.

Another option is to use the `std::basic_ios::exceptions()` function of `std::fstream()`, to trigger an exception when the stream state runs into an error condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The file did get created. A file search on my whole disk showed me, that it was not created in the folder containing the source file but somewhere else. Since i used ROS [link](http://www.ros.org/), catkin_make and the roslaunch tool, the file was created in the /proc folder. Again thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths do work with streams.  You have two interesting cases though.  The tilde (`~`) is a special character that some shells interpret.  I suspect that fstream doesn't do that interpretation.  As to the example of `"./test.txt"`, I think the previous comment is correct - that file has been created - it's just not where you expected it.