# Relative path with fstream c++

Tags: c++, file, relative-path, fstream

I try to load a file with fstream. The code looks like this

```
file.open("../levels/level0.lvl");
if (file.is_open()) {
    while (!file.eof()) {
        std::getline(file, Str);
        list = ReadLine(Str, list);
    }
}
```

But it loads nothing. Yes only if the path is absolute. 
How can I make the path relative?

The folder "levels" is hosted in the debug folder. same folder as the exe.

Comment: Your relative path is valid.  Are you possibly confusing your *active directory* with *your executable's directory*?

Comment: You're right. Thanks and sorry for this stupid mistake

Comment: @Beatnory _`while (!file.eof())`_ You should also note: [**Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"The folder "levels" is hosted in the debug folder. same folder as the exe."*

It doesn't matter in which position the `levels` folder is in relation to the executable's path.
The relevant folder to determine the relative path is the working directory where your executable is actually started from.

---

See here: [fstream doesn't resolve path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076633/fstream-doesnt-resolve-path/28077472#28077472) also.

Comment: Aren't these the same though? Where the executable is starting from and where the folder is?

Answer (score 0):

Path handling is OS specific. The correct way to handle this is to add a way of the user specifying the path to your application and then use that path. For example, you could add a command line option `--level-file=<path>`. Then your program can read the path from that option and pass it to the fstream constructor.

See my answer to this question for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40980510/2345997