# How to open a file with relative path in C++?

Tags: c++, relative-path, ifstream, absolute-path

I am writing test cases right now and I created some test files which I try to read. The absolute path is:

```
/home/user/code/Project/source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat
```

but testing with an absolute path is bad for obvious reasons. So I try to convert the absolute path into a relative one and I don't know why it doesn't work. I created a file with the relative path

```
findme.dat
```

and I found it in

```
/home/user/code/Project/build/source/Project/components/Project/test/findme.dat
```

so I created the relative path

```
/../../../../../../source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat
```

but the file is not open and not associated with the `is` object,
`std::ifstream is (path);`, and the `is.is_open()` function returns fulse.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the current working directory of your program? The path you provide has to be relative to the CWD. Also, since you start the path with `/` that means you start *at the root*, and since there is no parent directory for the root that means `/..` is the same as `/`, leading to your path being equal to `/source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat`

Comment: It all depends on current working directory. i.e where your program is placed.

Comment: Your 'relative' path is not relative.
It should start with a dot instead of a slash.
e.g ./../../../../../../source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat

Comment: Thanks guys, you helped a lot!

Comment: **Update: For c++ 17+:** https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are using is not at all a relative path. Sure you are using the relative path syntax but not the actual meaning of what it is.

> /../../../../../../source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat

This path starts with a / which means root then finds it parent which return root again since root has no parent and goes on... The simplified version of this is:

> /source/Project/components/Project/test/file.dat

So it will look for folder source in root which of-course doesn't exist.

What you should do is something like this (assuming your code is in project folder):

> ./test/file.dat

or if it is in some other folder within Project folder you can do something like this:

> ../test/file.dat

../ take you to the parent of your current code directory which under this case's assumption is Project.