# Cmake include directories

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I have a folder structure like this: Project/Libraries/Math, Project/Libraries/Math2.

In the Project folder I have the main.cpp, and the CMakeLists.txt with the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (CppMain)
add_executable(CppMain main.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR))
```

In the Math folder I have the header MyVectors.h and in the Math2 folder I have MyMatrices.h, that I would like to include in the main.cpp file, and this works as:

```
#include "Libraries/Math/MyVectors.h"
#include "Libraries/Math2/MyMatrices.h"
```

The problem is that also the header MyVectors.h includes the header MyMatrices.h at the same way, but the linker doesn't find it. What can I modify in the CMakeLists to fix this problem?

Comment: Are MyVector.h and MyMatrices.h placed in same folder?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. They are in two different folders.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a classical case of relative paths. You have done this to include the files in `main.cpp`

```
#include "Libraries/Math/MyVectors.h"
#include "Libraries/Math2/MyMatrices.h"
```

In order for a file to access is parent directory you can use `../` The  following lines should be introduced to `MyVectors.h`:

```
#include "../Math2/MyMatrices.h"
```

What does it signify? Well your file `MyVectors.h` is in `Math` folder when you use `../` it takes you to the parent directory of `Math` which is `Libraries`. From there you can simply follow the path to your required directory.

More detail can be found on this answer by me on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910234/2555668