# In Visual Studio 2019 can't read text file from release mode but works fine in debug (running within VS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, release

I am currently trying to read in a text file for use in a project but when running in release form (running the .exe file from a command window) the file doesn't read in. But yet in debug mode it works fine. I have tried having the files in the same directory as the .exe file but it doesn't seem to find it and I don't know why?

The code:

```
        std::cout << "Acquiring data file..." << endl;
    std::cout << "Reading data file..." << endl;
    
    ifstream tempData;
    
    tempData.open("temp_lincolnshire_short.txt");
    if (tempData.is_open()) {

        std::cout << tempData.rdbuf() << endl;
        
    }
    else {

        cout << "Reading failed..." << endl;
    }
    tempData.close();
    std::cout << "Data file closed." << endl;
```

Comment: Provide an absolute path instead of a relative path, see if that works.

Comment: I'll give that a go but the application needs to be used on other pcs so the absolute path would break

Comment: This is probably due to the different default directory used for debug and release builds. You need to make sure your txt file is in the correct subdirectory (the same one the exe is located in), or use an absolute path to it.

Comment: @CallumGodfrey I'm only stating to provide an absolute path simply as a test. Because I doubt there's an actual reason other than directories that's causing this behavior.

Comment: Yeah the absolute path worked so it is the directories that's causing the issue and I have the text file in the same directory as the .exe file so I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong?

Comment: VS uses different directories for debug and release modes. You must make sure the text file exists in the release folder too.

Comment: in debug, mode file will read where vcxproj is present while in release mode file will read where exe is present.. i mean respective root directory

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was a relative path as identified on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910234/3795116 which ended up being:

```
myFile.open("../Release/frequency.dat", ios::in);
```

*changing *myFile* to whatever your variable is.